# ajax fails obtaining the JSON string from GET service

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to obtain the response from a GET services the ajax function always run into error section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-- jquery -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<!-- bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax(
{
    url: "http://localhost:8080/POC-WebApplication/obtenerusuarios",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
    {

        alert("success");
    },
    error: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        alert("FAIL!!!!\ndata: "+data+"\ntextStatus: "+textStatus+"\njqXHR: "+jqXHR);
    }
});
</script>
```

When the browser executes the code I got this results:

- data: [object Object]
- textStatus: parserror
- jqXHR: Error: jQuery1111.....3111 was not called

I tried with dataType: "json" but I got this error in the chrome debug console:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

and the alerts print:

- data: [object Object]
- textStatus: error
- jqXHR: Error:

****EDITED****

I solved it using this chrome app: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

I encourage everyone with the same problem as me to use it.

Comment: What URL are you using to access this document?

Comment: Try your AJAX Url as `/POC-WebApplication/obtenerusuarios` only.

Answer (score 0):

As far I understand i think you have to add these lines to you `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```